# Mock a method that raise an exception a number of times

Tags: django, python-2.7, mocking

I have looked for how to do this all day, without luck. I'm using Django 1.11 and Python 2.7 (no possibility to upgrade).

I have a method that calls an external API. This API sometimes fails with 504 or 502 errors. So, we decide to, in that case, retrieve the call some times (3 times for now). So, I wrote something like this.

```
def call_external_api(arg_1, arg_2):
        attempts = 3
        data = None

        ext_api = ExternalAPI() # wrapper class, its method call the external api
        while attempts > 0:
            try:
                data = ext_api.get_data_details(arg_1=arg_1, arg_2=arg_2)
            except Exception as exception:
                attempts -= 1
                log_message(exception)
                raise ExternalAPIError('Error calling EXT-API: %s' % str(exception))
        return data
```

So, I want to test this, but I do not know how to mock the exception. I know that it is possible to use `@patch(SomeClass, 'method_name')` to simulate the call to another class, but how to simulate the exception, so the code enters on the except branch and reduces "attempt," repeating the cycle?

Notes: I thought that if I can mock the exception, I could test that log_message was called 3 times. What do you think about this approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an api response in data and it is returning other than 200 then you can raise Exception.

```
def call_external_api(arg_1, arg_2):
        attempts = 3
        data = None

        ext_api = ExternalAPI() # wrapper class, its method call the external api
        while attempts > 0:
            try:
                data = ext_api.get_data_details(arg_1=arg_1, arg_2=arg_2)
                if data.status_code != 200:
                   raise Exception("Server Error")
            except Exception as exception:
                attempts -= 1
                log_message(exception)
                raise ExternalAPIError('Error calling EXT-API: %s' % str(exception))
        return data
```

Note: get_data_details should return the response.